# X-debugger shows unexpected changes when watching variables in a PHP server-side script

Tags: centos, php, watch, xdebug

I want to know if the X-debugger and/or Apache web-server could be the cause of a debugging issue that I just started seeing. I'm including the following code to show where the unexpected values occur.

Here is the script code:

```
// The value of $retrim is FALSE.
// The value of $lowValue is "Smokeymoke".
// The value of $highValue is "Te".
//  The value of $k is 1 (ONE).

while( true ) {    // The condition of the while loop isn't actually true, but is a detail
                   // that only adds complexity to this issue so isn't shown here.

    $newLowValue  = substr( $lowValue,  0, $k );     // When executed $newLowValue is
                                                     // "Smokeymoke", but should be "S"!

    if( $retrim ) {     // The value of $retrim is FALSE, so this if-then block of code
                        // isn't executed.

        $newHighValue = substr( $highValue, 0, $k );

    } // End of if( $retrim ) ...

  if( $newLowValue !== $newHighValue ) {     // However, the value of $newHightValue at
                                             // this point doesn't show "Te", but rather
                                             // "T" (!), but since the two aren't the same,
                                             // even if wrong, causes the while-loop to
                                             // exit.

      break;

  } // End of if( $newLowValue  !== $newHighValue ) ...

  ++$k;

} // End of while( true ) ...
```

The while-loop, in the above code, exits with a break statement when `$newLowValue` is not same as `$newHighValue`. Otherwise, the loop continues executing.

However, with the values shown, the loop exits because `$newLowValue` and `$newHighValue` differ, even though the code didn't execute properly as per the comments in the code above, causing the values of these variables not to be correct.

The attachment shows the X-debugger output that I see when debugging the while-loop, above.

[image: Code Segment]

```
The server information from phpinfo.php -
  OS version:               Linux (CentOS) 3.10.0-514.16.1.el7.x86_64 #1
                            SMP Wed Apr 12 15:04:24 UTC 2017 x86_64
  Apache version:           Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.6.30
  X-Debugger version:       2.5.3
  PHP version:              5.6.30
  Symfony 2 version:        2.8.28 - app/dev/debug

The client is running -
  PHP Storm version:        PhpStorm 2016.3.3 Build #PS-163.13906.21, built on
                            March 8, 2017
  Chrome Browser version:   Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)
  Windows 10 Home version:  1803 OS build 17134.885
```

Comment: Disable the debugger then, make debug outputs from directly within the script instead … then you’ll know whether this is an issue _caused_ by the debugger, or not.

Comment: Please provide self-contained example (the whole file that can be copy-paste and tested locally). I've tried your code on PHP 7.2, Xdebug 2.7.2 & PhpStorm 2019.1.3 .. and `$newLowValue` quals "S" as expected. Just script exited abnormally few moments later as "Undefined variable: newHighValue" (which is true). P.S. Your IDE, PHP  & Xdebug are quite old. Would be better if you would check it using latest/more modern versions.

Comment: LazyOne, you're correct about the versions, but I'm close to releasing the project.  When that's done, I'll upgrade the software, as you suggest, and rewrite the code to account for the changes.

Comment: Misorude, I considered that, but before doing so, I looked for another function to handle the substr function and found mb_substr.  I've been working on this project for quite a while, and while none of the data actually requires multi-byte strings, I had added support for them, but forgot about it ... until today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comments.  Here is the problem that I found ...

It isn't clear from the data that I showed in my question, but the side-effect of using **substr** on multi-byte character strings was that sometimes the function returned the original un-truncated string, no matter the value of length parameter.  Changing from **substr** to **mb_substr** stopped this from happening.

Additionally, the **if( retrim )** tests, which were assigned **true** and **false** boolean values, would fail and the code block inside the if-then statements would execute even when they shouldn't.  When I changed these to **if( retrim === true )** along with changing to the **mb_substr** function, the side-effects stopped occurring.

Comment: Thanks for posting your findings, could be helpful to others!